# PostgreSQL - Error: SQL state: XX000

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Population"
(
  "Id" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"population_Id_seq"'::regclass),
  "Name" character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  "Description" character varying(1024),
  "IsVisible" boolean NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT "pk_Population" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

And a select function that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Population_SelectAll"()
  RETURNS SETOF "Population" AS
$BODY$select
  "Id",
  "Name",
  "Description",
  "IsVisible"
from "Population";
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'sql' STABLE
  COST 100
```

Calling the select function returns all the rows in the table as expected.

I have a need to add a couple of columns to the table (both of which are foreign keys to other tables in the database). This gives me a new table def as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "Population"
(
  "Id" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"population_Id_seq"'::regclass),
  "Name" character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  "Description" character varying(1024),
  "IsVisible" boolean NOT NULL,
  "DefaultSpeciesId" bigint NOT NULL,
  "DefaultEcotypeId" bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "pk_Population" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_Population_DefaultEcotypeId" FOREIGN KEY ("DefaultEcotypeId")
      REFERENCES "Ecotype" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "fk_Population_DefaultSpeciesId" FOREIGN KEY ("DefaultSpeciesId")
      REFERENCES "Species" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

and function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Population_SelectAll"()
  RETURNS SETOF "Population" AS
$BODY$select
  "Id",
  "Name",
  "Description",
  "IsVisible",
  "DefaultSpeciesId",
  "DefaultEcotypeId"
from "Population";
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'sql' STABLE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Calling the function after these changes results in the following error message:

```
ERROR: could not find attribute 11 in subquery targetlist
SQL state: XX000
```

**What is causing this error and how do I fix it? I have tried to drop and recreate the columns and function - but the same error occurs.**

Platform is PostgreSQL 8.4 running on Windows Server. Thanks.

Comment: did you populate the "Population"."DefaultSpeciesId" and ."DefaultEcotypeId" columns with data after adding them?

Comment: yes, I added the columns, added some values to the existing table rows, then setup the "not null" and fk constraints on them.

Answer (score 8):

Did you dropping and recreating the function? 
By the way, you gotta love how user friendly Postgres is. What other database would you hugs and kisses(XXOOO) as an error state?

Comment: Yes, tried that - no joy. The words "user friendly" and "Postgres" should not be allowed together in the same sentence :p

Comment: I like your XXOOO comment.

Answer (score 1):

When I've seen something similar in the past, it was because the database connection cached certain function attributes. So if I was using pgAdmin, I had to close the SQL editor window and establish a new connection in order to get the function to work correctly. If you haven't already, be sure you are testing the function on new db connections.

I thought the issue was fixed a few versions ago in PostgreSQL, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - already tried and it made no difference. I've since worked around this by deleting all the fks referencing the table, dropping it outright, then recreating it. Works OK now, but a far from ideal solution!

Comment: I tested this with postgresql 8.4 and pgAdmin 1.10. Worked

Answer (score 1):

Found a bit easier for me solution: created a backup of the database and restored it from this backup.